# Regex for string matching following criteria

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a `Regex` object to match strings with following specifications:

1. String contains minimum 6 and maximum 50 alpha numeric.
2. It can contain only characters and special characters except “*”, “/”, “ "”, “:”, “<”, “>”, “?”, “\”, “|”, “™”, “©”, “®”.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? This reads too much like homework for me to even attempt an answer without you giving an indication of what you tried.

Comment: If you think of "except" something, have you considered about control characters and Unicode characters?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93804/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-C-NET) one & try something, if then also not got solution then post the tried example here you will exact solution for it.

Comment: I tried and came upto /[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,50}/. I couldnt find out how to satisfy condition 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"^[^ put_anything_you_dont_want_like_specials_and_space_in_here]{6,50}$"`

Answer (score 0):

[your list of accepted characters]{6,50}